# recaptcha works on localhost not on ip-Address showing ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key :

Tags: recaptcha-v3

recaptchaV3 works well on localhost but while testing with my ip address it shows   ERROR for site owner:
        Invalid domain for site key[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9D0R.png)

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm running into the same issue, but in reverse. My localhost doesn't work, but my live one does.